# OmniFaces loading/unloading ViewScopedBean

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

Trying to narrow in on our issue we are upgrading from Jboss 6 EAP (JSF 2.1) to Jboss 7 EAP (JSF 2.2).  Our working application now has an issue with OmniFaces ViewScoped beans.

**Versions:**

- Mojarra 2.2.14
- OminFaces 2.6.9
- PrimeFaces 6.2.5

We have a datatable like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="tblLegalHolds" widgetVar="tableLegalHolds" var="row"
        rowKey="#{row.id}" filterEvent="enter" 
        lazy="true"
        value="#{bean.lazyDataModel}"
        rows="15">
```

**NOTE:** Our bean is OmniFaces ViewScoped and our table is working fine at this point!

**Problem:**
Next we add a column that contains a navigation to a new page like this:

```
<p:column width="60" exportable="false">
    <p:button value="Open" outcome="legal-hold-edit">
        <f:param name="id" value="#{row.id}" />
    </p:button>
</p:column>
```

Now our bean is getting loaded and unloaded immediately and if we do a View Source of the HTML we see the Omnifaces script added twice like so...

```
OmniFaces.Unload.init('f1c1ff81-c87f-4406-b98f-a3eaff977e96');
OmniFaces.Unload.init('45e7de9d-53c7-4426-a972-797c48c46733');
```

We added @PostConstruct to our ViewScoped beans to prove its getting called twice.  Our faces-config.xml looks like this for that Navigation.

```
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>legal-hold-edit</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/legal/legal-hold-edit.xhtml</to-view-id>
    <redirect include-view-params="true"/>
</navigation-case>
```

Now what is interesting is if we remove the "include-view-params" in faces-config.xml like the code below everything starts working fine the ViewScoped bean is created only once and only 1 OmniFaces.Unload.init script is added to the page.

```
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>legal-hold-edit</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/legal/legal-hold-edit.xhtml</to-view-id>
    <redirect/>
</navigation-case>
```

As an added note our outcome page is using o:viewparam to receive the param like this:

```
    <f:metadata>
        <o:viewParam name="id" value="#{legalHoldForm.legalHold}" required="false" />
        <f:event type="preInvokeAction" listener="#{controller.initializeViewLegalHold}" />
   </f:metadata>
```

So my questions are:

1. Why does removing "include-view-params" make it work?
2. Is this a bug similar to this recent ViewScoped issue? : https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/463

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Mojarra. It's indirectly calling the `PreDestroyViewMapEvent` when figuring out the view parameters for the other view.

During the render response phase, when the URL for an `UIOutcomeTarget` component (e.g. `<p:button>`) is to be generated, and `includeViewParams` is set to `true` (as defined in your navigation case), then it needs to consult all `<f:viewParam>` of the target view. In order to achieve this, it will need to build an `UIViewRoot` instance of it.

However, it actually temporarily sets that new `UIViewRoot` as the current view root of the faces context in order to access the `<f:viewParam>`. It will restore the original view, but this is where it goes wrong in Mojarra. [It is restoring `context.setProcessingEvents(true)` too early](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/2.3.3.102/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/application/view/ViewMetadataImpl.java#L137). It should actually have done it *after* restoring the original view.

For now, your best bet is to report this issue against Mojarra and avoid using `includeViewParams` in combination with OmniFaces `@ViewScoped`.

Answer (score 1):

Issue reported: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4503

PR Provided: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/pull/4730

This fix will be included in 2.3.15, 3.0.1 and 4.0.0 of Mojarra.